# Redirect with header parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpclient

Is it possible to set parameters in the header of an `HttpResponse`, then redirect?

I tried something like this:

```
Response.Headers.Add("test", "1234"); 
Response.Redirect(www.targetpage.com);
```

and then

```
 var result = Request.Headers["test"];
```

My problem is that I don't find the parameter in my request `result` is always null and I cannot pass the the parameters in the url I need a solution with the header, thanks.

Comment: Here are the explanations why you cannot do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070430/response-redirect-with-headers

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy it doesn't say that i cannot do that

Comment: isn't your Redirect flushing everything? You need to explain a bit more

Comment: @TMcKeown typical stackoverflow answer, isn't it ?!

Comment: A redirect on the client will not forward the redirect headers. Best you can do is use the Referral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting the client, so anything you sent to the client in the Response is probably flushed/discarded. If your intent is to control the redirect then you'd need to handle that in js on the client.

There are many ways to implement your own messaging:

[How to send data from C# to JavaScript/AJAX webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917536/how-to-send-data-from-c-sharp-to-javascript-ajax-webpage)

Comment: and can you tell me how to do that ?

Comment: Many ways... the most basic is to do an onload js coding trap or build a more elaborate ajax based messaging system.